# Is every metric space realcompact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, realcompact-spaces

Let $X$ be a space and $\beta X$ denote the Stone-Cech compactification of $X$.

$X$ is *realcompact* if for each $p\in \beta X\setminus X$ there is a continuous $f:X\to[0,\infty)$ such that $\beta f (p)=\infty$, where $\beta f:\beta X\to[0,\infty]$ is the extension of $f$.

It is fairly easy to see that every *separable* metric space $X$ is realcompact. Embed $X$ into $[0,1]^\omega$. If $p\in \overline X \setminus X$ then there is a sequence of points $(x_n)$ in $X$ converging to $p$. Set $f(x_n)=n$ and extend  $f$ to a function from $X$ into $[0,\infty)$ using Tietze's theorem.

But what if the space is not separable?

Are all metric spaces realcompact?  How about complete metric spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s a consistency result. If there are no measurable cardinals, every metric space is realcompact; this is $\mathbf{15.24}$ in Gillman and Jerison, *Rings of Continuous Functions*. If $\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal, the discrete topology on $\kappa$ is metrizable but not realcompact.

Comment: Do you know if every completely metrizable realcompact space is separable?

Comment: @ForeverMozart: A discrete space of cardinality $\omega_1$ is completely metrizable and realcompact but not separable.

Comment: If measurable cardinals exist, is it true that every metrisable space whose cardinality is smaller than every measurable cardinal is realcompact?

Comment: @JonasFrey: Yes: it follows from Theorem $2$ in [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-032-01/S0002-9939-1972-0288724-3/S0002-9939-1972-0288724-3.pdf) [PDF].

Comment: Isn't the precise statement of theorem **15.24** that the metric space $X$ is realcompact if $|X|$ is non-measurable? So it should answer @JonasFrey question directly.

Comment: @Jakobian: Yes, but I didn’t have G&J at hand when I answered that question (and in any case I liked the argument in the Rice paper.)

Comment: hmm, but the property of being measurable is not "upward closed" in the cardinal hierarchy, is it? so does that mean that there are realcompact spaces with non-realcompact subspaces?

Comment: @JonasFrey: There are. Let $X$ be any Tikhonov space that is not realcompact; then $\beta X$ is a compact (hence realcompact) space having $X$ as a non-realcompact subspace. (And you don’t actually need all of $\beta X$: the Hewitt realcompactification $\nu X$ of $X$, which is a subspace of $\beta X$, is enough.)

Comment: ok that makes sense.